# robots.txt is not allowing the AMP page

Tags: robots.txt, amp-html

I had a page for my site as (as an example) `www.example.com/amp/amp-list.html`.

When I validate it in https://search.google.com/search-console/amp, it throws error:

> Page cannot be reached
>   This could be because the page is unavailable or blocked by robots.txt
>   LEARN MORE

My robots.txt:

```
# robotstxt.org

User-agent: *
Disallow: /auth/google
Disallow: /auth/facebook
```

Can anyone please suggest me help to allow my page?

Comment: remove the disallow statements...?

Comment: Hi,andrew I am putting that for google and facebook and if I disallow might that gets effected?

Comment: @MMR Keep in mind that `amp` is a project run by Google...

Comment: The robots.txt you posted doesn’t block crawling the example URL you posted.

Comment: Hi unor,it blocked my page when i tested it in google webmaster.

Comment: Hi War10ck,yes but  why the validation is blocked by the robot.txt file?.

Answer (score 0):

I think the site: www.example.com/amp/amp-list.html need access to the blocked URL.
Google render the whole site incl. all externe file like .js, .css.
So the error in the Search Console is that Google dont't have acces to your Auth Directory.
You can do follow in your robots.txt:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /auth/google
Allow: /auth/facebook
User-agent: *
Disallow: /auth/google
Disallow: /auth/facebook
```

Keep in mind that the rule allow for the Google bot must be before the deny rule.